# Avoid function call in binding

Tags: angular

I know that i should avoid function calls in a binding, as they're called on every change cycle. I have the following problem where i would like to avoid the function call but i can't find a way around it.

This is only a simplified example but it should show the problem:

some-template.html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let control of group.Controls">
    <div [ngSwitch]="control.ControlTypeName" >
        <input *ngSwitchCase="'int'" type="text" [formControlName]="getFormControlName(control.PropertyName)">
        ...
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

some-component.ts

```
public getFormControlName(propertyName: string) {
    return this.someArray.find(x => x.key === propertyName).formControlName;
}
```

The problem is that the property i need for the `[formControlName]` input, is not in the 'control' object i loop over with `*ngFor`. The property is in a different array and i'm only able to find it by calling a function.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: You can store all the calculated `formControl` names in a separate object say `formControls` identified by `control.ControlTypeName` key. Probably you should do this inside setter method of `group.Controls`.You can move the functionality of `getFormControlName()` to its setter. So that whenever the value of `group.controls` changes, it recalculates `formControlNames` 
And then in your template you could access it like `formControls[control.ControlTypeName]`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this, you should have a look-up table (hash table / map / object), indexed by array element `key` with `formControlName` as value:

some-component.ts

```
some_array = [{key: 'a', formControlName: 'b'}, ...];
control_name = this.some_array.reduce(
                   (obj, el) => ((obj[el.key] = el.formControlName), obj), {});
```

some-template.html

```
<input *ngSwitchCase="'int'" [formControlName]="control_name[control.PropertyName]" type="text">
```